# Get the count of results

Tags: content-hub

I am unable to fetch the count of the results in Content Hub. How to get the result of the "**asset items**" count in rest API
reference API call: `https://{{hostname}}/api/entities/query?query=String('Title')=='Golf'`

Answer (score 1):

There are two properties within the response payload that will help here, depending on what you're looking for:

1. `total_items`: This is the total number of entities within Content Hub that match the query.
2. `returned_items`: This is the number of entities included within the current request's response. This can be modified on subsequent requests by adding `skip` and `take` parameters in the query string to return different 'pages' of results.